# Similar function in C++ to Python's strip()?

Tags: c++, string, strip

There is a very useful function in Python called [strip()](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html?highlight=strip#string.strip). Any similar ones in C++?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352055/best-algorithm-to-strip-leading-and-trailing-spaces-in-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to trim std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python strip a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038824/python-strip-a-string)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mimic Python's strip() function in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488372/mimic-pythons-strip-function-in-c)

Comment: [`boost::trim`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/trim.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing built-in; I used to use something like the following:

```
template <std::ctype_base::mask mask>
class IsNot
{
    std::locale myLocale;       // To ensure lifetime of facet...
    std::ctype<char> const* myCType;
public:
    IsNot( std::locale const& l = std::locale() )
        : myLocale( l )
        , myCType( &std::use_facet<std::ctype<char> >( l ) )
    {
    }
    bool operator()( char ch ) const
    {
        return ! myCType->is( mask, ch );
    }
};

typedef IsNot<std::ctype_base::space> IsNotSpace;

std::string
trim( std::string const& original )
{
    std::string::const_iterator right = std::find_if( original.rbegin(), original.rend(), IsNotSpace() ).base();
    std::string::const_iterator left = std::find_if(original.begin(), right, IsNotSpace() );
    return std::string( left, right );
}
```

which works pretty well.  (I now have a significantly more complex
version which handles UTF-8 correctly.)

Answer (score 9):

I use this:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

std::string strip(const std::string &inpt)
{
    auto start_it = inpt.begin();
    auto end_it = inpt.rbegin();
    while (std::isspace(*start_it))
        ++start_it;
    while (std::isspace(*end_it))
        ++end_it;
    return std::string(start_it, end_it.base());
}
```

Comment: If inpt="\t", then the last step will throw "string too long" exception.

Comment: A safer version is provided below.

Comment: The second `while` should be run only if `start_it` doesn't point past the string: `if (start_it != inpt.end()) { while (std::isspace(*end_it)) { ++end_it; } }`.

Answer (score 1):

```
void strip(std::string &str)
{
    if  (str.length() != 0)
    {
    auto w = std::string(" ") ;
    auto n = std::string("\n") ;
    auto r = std::string("\t") ;
    auto t = std::string("\r") ;
    auto v = std::string(1 ,str.front()); 
    while((v == w) || (v==t) || (v==r) || (v==n))
    {
        str.erase(str.begin());
        v = std::string(1 ,str.front());
    }
    v = std::string(1 , str.back()); 
    while((v ==w) || (v==t) || (v==r) || (v==n))
    {
        str.erase(str.end() - 1 );
        v = std::string(1 , str.back());
    }
}
```

Comment: it work with me good , it is not well optimized but it do the job correctly . i made it void to use it in for_each algorithm .

Answer (score 0):

This is on top of the answer provided by Ferdi Kedef to make it safer.

```
void strip(std::string& str)
{
    if (str.length() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    auto start_it = str.begin();
    auto end_it = str.rbegin();
    while (std::isspace(*start_it)) {
        ++start_it;
        if (start_it == str.end()) break;
    }
    while (std::isspace(*end_it)) {
        ++end_it;
        if (end_it == str.rend()) break;
    }
    int start_pos = start_it - str.begin();
    int end_pos = end_it.base() - str.begin();
    str = start_pos <= end_pos ? std::string(start_it, end_it.base()) : "";
}
```